# R package: create platform-specific function

Tags: r

I am developing an R-package with a function that should return file names with full path, either by being given a path and a couple of file names, or - if under Windows in interactive mode - by opening a file browser with `choose.files()` showing only files ending in `csv`, `dat` or `txt`.

Since `choose.files()` and variable `Filters` only exist under Windows, this happens in an appropriate `if()` clause. However, `R CMD CHECK` under Linux generates a NOTE about global variable `Filters` having no visible binding. Even though this is just a note, I have been asked to fix it by creating platform specific functions such that the `choose.files()` branch is never even seen under Linux. How can I do this?

```
fileNames <- function() {
    files <- character(0)
    if(interactive() && (.Platform$OS.type == "windows")) {
        myFilt <- rbind(Filters, txtCsvDat=c("Data files (*.txt, *.csv, *.dat)",
                                             "*.txt;*.csv;*.dat"))
        files <- choose.files(filters=myFilt[c("txtCsvDat", "All"), ], index=1)
    }    
    return(files)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS-specific code doesn't in general seem like a good idea, but you can use sub-directories to define functions

```
MyPkg/R/windows/fileName.R
```

If necessary (e.g., because you will not implement fileName on non-Windows), include conditional collation order in the DESCRIPTION file

```
Collate.unix: shared.R
Collate.windows: shared.R windows/fileName.R
```

and arrange for conditional exports in the NAMESPACE file (again, if necessary)

```
if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows")
    export(fileName)
```

Conditional collation is documented in `RShowDoc("R-exts")` (Section 1.1.1, search for Collate.windows); I'm not sure that there is a good reference for allowable syntax in NAMESPACE files. The NAMESPACE approach is used in the [parallel](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/parallel) package.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Using `get` should fix it :

```
 get("Filters")
```

Comment: +1 because this gets rid of the note. However, this does not implement platform-dependent functions in the sense that @MartinMorgan's answer does.